# Permanently changing table column order without creating a new layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, column, refactor

In QGIS 3.18. The order of columns in a shapefile's attribute table can be changed by the following methods:

1. using the Organize Columns tool in the attribute table;
2. using the Refactor Fields tool;
3. older versions of QGIS had the Table Manager Plugin.

(You can also change field order on forms using Drag and Drop Designer, but not column order in the attribute table.)

The problem with 1. is that it is not permanent; the column order is remembered by the project but not the shapefile.

- The settings can be saved in a style file (`.qml`) but if the shapefile is to be distributed and used by different people, adding an extra file and an extra task to everyone's workflow makes it less likely that the file will be viewed and used as intended.
- This would not be such an issue if it weren't for the fact that **some common tasks do* alter the column order permanently and automatically** (example: renaming a field moves that column to the end, with no possibility of moving it back).

The problem with 2. is that it creates a new layer.

- I often find myself in the position of wanting to rename a field without changing its position, or create a new field that I want in a particular position. Each time, I have to refactor-- which creates a new temp layer, which I have to resave and restyle, and then also rename the file to the original name (deleting the original one) if there are dynamic links associated with that layer.

Seeing as QGIS *does* have the ability to change column order without creating a new layer (it does so automatically upon renaming a field, etc), it seems like it should also be possible to to *allow the user to control that*. **Is there any newer trick in the GUI (in late 2021) that I've missed that would allow this?** If there are additional plugins or scripts that do, that is also great, but as mentioned this layer will be distributed to various users, and I prefer to not have to ask them to install additional items along with it.

Comment: are you aware that you can copy & paste a layers' style from one to another? so if you refactor&load that new layer, just right click the old one, Styles -> Copy Styles -> All Style Categories and paste it to the new one (Style-> Paste). Does not solve your whole problem but makes your Option 2) a little bit more comfortable maybe

Comment: Regarding the `.qml`, if you give it the same name as the shapefile it will be automatically loaded by QGIS when adding the Shapefile

Comment: @JGH, I was unaware of that but since you've mentioned it it has become my favorite workaround. It doesn't completely solve what I see as a pending problem, but it has solved my immediate issue of distributing a layer to people without needing to ask them to load a style file. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find a simple way to organize fields with QGIS you can use OpenJUMP. You can re-order, remove, or add fields. It is also possible to change the data types of fields if data allows that. Apply changes and save the layer and the new field order will be permanent also for QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Is OpenJUMP FOSS?

Comment: Certainly, GPL 2. I recommend to download PLUS version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP/1.16/. The zip is perhaps easiest,just unzip and run oj_windows.bat or oj_linux.sh from the bin directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for info!