# QGIS: Is there a fast way to export an attribute table without every column scrambling up

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export

I have an attribute table where I arranged every column using 'organise column'.
If i try to export the attribute table to XML then all the columns are scrambled again.
I could rearrange them using refactor field, but i have 50 columns and that takes alot of time.

Is there any plugin or tool I can use so I don't need to manually rearrange everything?

Comment: Have you tried rearranging things in Excel and then re-importing back into QGIS?

Comment: Yes that works, but thats not my problem. 
I use a shapefile for inventory of trees.
There are alot of fields i use with various stuff (boleans, dropdown menus,...).
I also have symbols that interact with fields.

I want to keep using that same shapefile over all my work on the field. 
But when I try to export the data to excel (because my clients ask for it), then the arrangement of my colums are scrambled.

Comment: Similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416584/permanently-changing-table-column-order-without-creating-a-new-layer-in-qgis